# Debugging C/C++ code with IPython

Tags: c++, python, debugging, ipython

Say I am in [IPython](http://ipython.org/) (e.g. on the [new QT console](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html)), and that I call a C++ library that I wrote from it (e.g. using [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG) or [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/python/doc/)). I would like to set a **breakpoint** in my C++ code and have the ability to interact with my C++ workspace (i.e. my variables when I hit the breakpoint) with IPython (e.g. plot my C++ variables, etc.).

In other words I would like to debug my C++ code from **IPython**. Is this at all possible? What are some tools I can use for this?

Comment: Have you tried the new python extensions in gdb 7? I know they're not IPython, but you can do quite a lot with them. This article is just one of many examples of how to use it. 
http://misspent.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/debugging-cc-and-cpython-using-gdb-7s-new-python-extension-support/

Answer (score 3):

(assuming you are on Linux)
You just need gdb. First set up configuration telling gdb where your source files are by adding this to `$HOME/.gdbinit`:

`directory absolute-path-to-source`

Now start `gdb python` and on the gdb prompt do:

`set args /usr/bin/ipython
run`

You can't directly do `gdb ipython` because ipython is a script. Please refer to the gdb documentation from here on.

Comment: I don't get an IPython prompt this way, I only see

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.

%quickref -> Quick reference.

help      -> Python's own help system.

object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

but no prompt, no console echo :-(

(this is with lldb, but still...)

Comment: It works with Python 2.7.13 / IPython 3.2.2 on OpenSuSE Leap 42. I didn't test it with other versions sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you won't be able to debug C++ code directly with IPython. What you can do, though, is use a C++ debugger to debug your C++ code.

Essentially, you tell your C++ debugger to execute whatever process you need to use to run your code (this could be IPython itself), and set a breakpoint in your C++ code (your debugger will know to wait for the appropriate DLL to be loaded if it's in a DLL). From there, you are debugging your part of the code that is running in the IPython process.